# Prettify.js (Syntax highlighting) not working on Tumblr theme!

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, tumblr

I'm trying to implement [`prettify.js`](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) in the same way as [this fellow here.](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/230548641/tumblr-blog-theme-javascript)

However it's not working. I copied his javascript from his page source to make sure it would work (since he wrote it in the blog post publicly I think I'm not plagiarizing, plus I give credit in my page source) and I included `prettify.js` from his dropbox links in his source as well to make sure the fixes he included were working. I also included Google's `prettify.css` as well as their `lang-css.js` because I am trying to highlight the syntax of CSS. Still not working. Below is a pastebin link of my Tumblr theme.

[Theme](http://pastebin.com/5m6JdrT4)

Since I have no actual Javascript development experience, and my CSS understanding is poor, I'm pretty sure I'm just doing something wrong. But I have no idea what. I was hoping someone on StackOverflow might know anything about this. (I realize I'm basically pasting my source and saying "HOW TO FIX????" but I don't know how to whittle down the problem any better.)

*Based on what rentzsch said in his post, does anyone know something I might be doing wrong even if I'm using his Javascript and some of his CSS?*

**EDIT: Fixed with new jQuery link, but now images don't appear.**

This code here causes images not to appear:

```
// CSS won't autoscale img heights given a max-width. So, we do it ourselves.
var maxWidth = $('.post_body').width();
$('img').each(function(){
   var scaledHeight;
   if (this.width > maxWidth) {
      scaledHeight = (this.height * maxWidth) / this.width;
      this.width = maxWidth;
      this.height = scaledHeight;
   }
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have broken urls to 2 JavaScript files. Change this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3./jquery.min.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-lisp.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/lang-lisp.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, it worked! Thanks so much. The first link was copied so I don't know why it didn't work, but the second was my error (shouldn't have mattered since it was for LISPy languages, but still nice to fix!). It's working now :)

Comment: There is no element in your theme with css class "post_body" so my guess is that images are set to 0 pixel width. Try to change `$('.post_body').width();` to `$('.post').width();`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for dealing with a newbie :) I guess I ought to buy a CSS/HTML book!